# I want to join two tables with a single query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to join `student_image` table with `student_details` table where

`image_id = student_id`

but Im stuck here, the query gives the student details, but now I want to add the student image to be displayed together with the student

Below is my query

`$query = $this->db->get_where('student_detail',array('reg_no'=>$reg_no))->result_array();`

Comment: use a select and Join statement to connect the two tables.

Comment: Are you using codeigniter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using CodeIgniter?

If you want to display `student_image` also you can do it like this:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('student_image a');
$this->db->join('student_details  b', 'a.image_id=b.student_detail_id','inner');
$this->db->where('b.student_detail',$reg_no);
return $this->db->get();
```

or you can do like it this:

```
$query = "select * from student_image as a join student_details as b on a.image_id=b.student_detail_id where b.student_detail=?"
return $this->db->query($query ,array($reg_no));
```

I hope this solves your problem

Comment: thanks, yeah, Im using code igniter...the code works perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

Myself, and probably anyone else has absolutely no idea what that db class you're using is, so we cannot help you with that detail.

A query like this is very basic. A plain query would look somewhat like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM student_details, student_image
  WHERE student_details.studentID = student_image.studentID
```

And that's it. Now you have to translate it into working with your db class...

I would recommend you learn basic mysql queries before you start using special pre-made classes. They make things a lot more complicated when you do not know what you want it to do yet.

-- The above query will get you the student details only if the row actually exists in both tables.
If you want it back even if it doesn't exist, you could use a `LEFT JOIN`, like so:

```
SELECT *
  FROM student_details
  LEFT JOIN student_image ON student_details.ID = student_image.ID
  WHERE student_details.ID = 'myStudentID'
```

The above query would retrieve a student's results.